# d3.scale.category20b always returning first color

Tags: d3.js

I try to use d3.scale.category.20b() to generate a color scale, problem is whatever number of the list I ask for, it always returns first element of the list.

```
var color = d3.scale.category20b();
console.log(color(X));
```

OR

```
console.log(d3.scale.category20b()(X);
```

No matter what X is, it always logs #393b79 which is the first elements, according to the [d3 API](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#wiki-category20c)

Comment: Hmm, looks like a bug to me. You should file an issue on the D3 website.

Comment: This might sound really stupid, but what is X in your example? ie, if you `console.log(X)` what does it return? For instance, if you happened to initialize X somewhere, hoping to later update its value and use it in your function up there, something might be wrong with updating the value... hence it systematically displaying the same thing.

Comment: @Joum I used X to represent numbers between 1 and 20. Should have said so.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can happen because categorical scales in d3 append to the domain as new data comes in. If every enter() creates a new categorical scale, the domain of the categorical scale remains the same.

As an example, please consider this jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/seldomawake/MV55j/1/
Here, we see that as data enters, we append to a categorical scale in the global namespace, `$colorScale` (specific code below).

```
function redraw(theData) {
    var localColorScale = d3.scale.category20c(); //< NOT USED HERE
    var svg = d3.select("svg");
    var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
                     .data(theData).enter().append("circle")
     var circleAttributes = circles.attr("cx", getRandomInt(50, 450))
                                   .attr("cy", getRandomInt(50, 450))
                                   .attr("r", function (d) { return d.value; })
                                   .style("fill", function () { return $colorScale(getRandomInt(0, 19)); });
}
```

However, if we were to replace `return $colorScale(getRandomInt(0, 19))` with `return localColorScale(getRandomInt(0, 19))`, we would no longer have the data append to the range of the categorical scale, and which would result in a single-color output.

<sub>Edit: fixing URL to jsfiddle.</sub>

Answer (score 8):

At first I thought this would have been a bug with D3.js so created [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8CaCn) which works fine.

```
var data = d3.range(0,20);
var color = d3.scale.category20b();

d3.select('.target').selectAll('div')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
        .append('div')
        .text(function(d){return color(d);})
        .attr('style', function(d){return "background-color:"+ color(d) + ";" ;})
```

It had been raised by others about version of D3 you are using. This looks unlikely to be the cause of your issue as the [code in question](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/commits/master/src/scale/category.js) has hardly been touched. If the code has not been touched much and others have no issue it raises the question of browser compatibly. I [sent my jsfiddle to browsershots](http://browsershots.org/http://jsfiddle.net/8CaCn/) and did not see any browser output a single block of color instead of the expected pretty color stripes.

After all this it seams there is not enough information to properly answer your problem. I suggest you have a look to see if X is really changing by making a small change to the code `console.log({'color':color(X), 'x':X})`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Which version of D3 are you using? I wrote a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VMVfp/4/) (D3 3.0.4), the colors are shown normally:

```
var color = d3.scale.category20b();

var svg = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
    .attr('width', 200)
    .attr('height', 100);

svg.append('rect')
    .attr('width', 100)
    .attr('height', 100)
    .attr('fill', color(0));

svg.append('rect')
    .attr('x', 100)
    .attr('width', 100)
    .attr('height', 100)
    .attr('fill', color(1));
```

The result is:

[image: Distinct colors]

Comment: Your fiddle is way better :)