# d3.scale.category20 is too smart for me

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Can anybody explain to me why these two expressions return different values...

```
log1.text(c20(1)); // "#aec7e8"
log2.text(d3.scale.category20()(1)); // "#1f77b4"
```

... in the following context

---

### Working example...

```js
    var c20 = d3.scale.category20(),
      col = d3.range(20).map(function(c) {
        return c20(c).replace("#", "0x")
      }),
      log1 = d3.select("#log1"),
      log2 = d3.select("#log2");

    log1.text(c20(1)); // "#aec7e8"
    log2.text(d3.scale.category20()(1)); // "#1f77b4"
    $("#user-agent").text(navigator.userAgent);
```

```css
#log div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="log">
  <div id="log1"></div>
  <div id="log2"></div>
</div>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <p id="user-agent"></p>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
  <div id="log1"></div>
  <div id="log2"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

The user agent reported in my system is

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36

---

I kind of get the above behaviour but this is very strange...

Why is this...

```
// method 1
d3.range(20).map(d3.scale.category20())

0   #1f77b4
1   #aec7e8
2   #ff7f0e
3   #ffbb78
4   #2ca02c
5   #98df8a
6   #d62728
7   #ff9896
8   #9467bd
9   #c5b0d5
10  #8c564b
11  #c49c94
12  #e377c2
13  #f7b6d2
14  #7f7f7f
15  #c7c7c7
16  #bcbd22
17  #dbdb8d
18  #17becf
19  #9edae5
```

different from this...

```
// method 2
d3.range(20).map(function(d, i) {
    return d3.scale.category20()(i);
})  

0   #1f77b4
1   #1f77b4
2   #1f77b4
3   #1f77b4
4   #1f77b4
5   #1f77b4
6   #1f77b4
7   #1f77b4
8   #1f77b4
9   #1f77b4
10  #1f77b4
11  #1f77b4
12  #1f77b4
13  #1f77b4
14  #1f77b4
15  #1f77b4
16  #1f77b4
17  #1f77b4
18  #1f77b4
19  #1f77b4
```

```js
var c20 = d3.scale.category20(),
  log1 = d3.select("#log1"),
  log2 = d3.select("#log2");

log1.text(c20(1)); // "#aec7e8"
log2.text(d3.scale.category20()(1)); // "#1f77b4"

d3.select("#t1").selectAll(".logs")
  .data(d3.range(20).map(d3.scale.category20()))
  .enter().append("tr").selectAll("td").data(function(d) {
    return [d]
  })
  .enter().append("td")
  .attr("class", "logs")
  .text(function(d, i, j) {
    return [j, d].join("\t")
  })

d3.select("#t2").selectAll(".logs")
  .data(d3.range(20).map(function(d, i) {
    return d3.scale.category20()(i);
  }))
  .enter().append("tr").selectAll("td").data(function(d) {
    return [d]
  })
  .enter().append("td")
  .attr("class", "logs")
  .text(function(d, i, j) {
    return [j, d].join("\t")
  })
```

```css
#log div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
  background: #ccc;
}
#t1,
#t2 {
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="log">
  <div id="log1"></div>
  <div id="log2"></div>
</div>
<div id="t1"></div>
<div id="t2"></div>
```

Just to explain, the reason I wanted to use method 2 above was because I needed to convert the hex strings into properly formatted hex numbers so I had to process the domain values on the way through.  The actual use case is this:

```
var col = d3.range(20).map(function(c){
        return d3.scale.category20()(c).replace("#", "0x")
    });
```

which doesn't work (and I still don't get why not), which is why I had to do this:

```
var c20 = d3.scale.category20(),
    col = d3.range(20).map(function(c){
        return c20(c).replace("#", "0x")
    });
```

Comment: It would be good if the drive-by anon down-voter + close-voter could put me out of my misery as to why this is a bad question...

Comment: Not my downvote, but you'll have to show an example that reproduces the issue. I get "#1f77b4" both ways: http://jsfiddle.net/pr9num7d/

Comment: I do get #aec7e8 #1f77b4 when running the code snippet on Chrome 47.0.2502.0 canary.

Comment: Same value for both the cases  http://jsfiddle.net/4b6duqdg/

Comment: @Tarang, yes, your right, I get the same as you when I run your fiddle.  What happens when you run the snippet I added?  I get different values.

Comment: @Juhana: good advice.  have added a minimum working example to demonstrate the behaviour.

Comment: @Tarang could it be because you refer to the exact same variable `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=color` and `document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML=color;`? See http://jsfiddle.net/4b6duqdg/3/ for reproduction of issue.

Comment: This is by design -- every time you instantiate an ordinal colour scale, you get a "fresh" one. This way you can put any colours into it, but the ones you've used always get mapped to the same value (as the domain is updated internally as pointed out in the comments to the answer). What is it you're actually trying to do?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, All I was trying to do was to get some verification on the behaviour and to get help in understanding what was going on.  If you look at the second snippet in my question, where I have `method1` and `method 2`, that's what I still don't understand.  Also, I don't understand what you are saying, the domain in this color scale is _pre-set_.  When I do this: `# ordinal(x)` I'm not setting any domains... I'm just getting the point on the _preset_ domain that maps to the range point. So... yeh... I don't follow you mate...

Comment: Ah, I see. Well in method 1 you're constructing the scale and then using *the same scale* for all calls. In method 2 you're constructing a *new scale* inside each call. In method 1, `d3.scale.category20()` is evaluated *before* it is used in the `map` (i.e. same scale), but in method 2 every time the `map` function is called. And you are actually setting the domain when asking for a value, see line 15 of https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/scale/ordinal.js @CoolBlue

Comment: Ok... yep, I see what you mean. But... I need to study more as to why it's necessary to behave like that.  To my way of thinking `(f = G(), f(x)) === G()(x); // true` should alway hold if a piece of code is rational.  Don't you think?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [d3.scale.category20b always returning first color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569205/d3-scale-category20b-always-returning-first-color)

Answer (score 5):

You can think of the palette 'building up' as it's being used. If you create the palette on the top, e.g.

`var palette = d3.scale.category20();`

and apply the palette different values in an iteration (e.g.

`selection.style('fill', function(d, i) {return palette(i);});`

then on each invocation, the palette checks if it already assigned a color for that value; if not, it'll attempt to give a new color (or recycle if you run out of colors).

In contrast, if you apply the value to a fresh palette in your iteration, it'll always just pull one value from *that one specific palette*:

`selection.style('fill', function(d, i) {return d3.scale.category20()(i);});`

The undesirable result is that all colors will be the same.

In other words, the `d3.scale.category20` isn't a pure function; it implicitly keeps track of its state. It's similar to e.g. using a random number generation that accepts a seed, i.e. deterministic: you don't want to recreate it in an iteration, otherwise the random number you pull will always be the same.

This issue (pre `D3v4`) speaks to the general value of functional programming, as there's anticipation that a function called with some values will always depend on just the supplied arguments, making testing easier too.

Comment: This is correct! Note, however, that this applies to all of D3's ordinal scales and is very well documented: [`d3.scale.ordinal`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Ordinal-Scales.md#ordinal) and [`ordinal(x)`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Ordinal-Scales.md#_ordinal). The [categorial color scales](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Ordinal-Scales.md#category20) being just ordinal scales with a preset range will inherit this behavior.

Comment: @altocumulus Indeed! I answered for those, who, like I a few years ago, run into it head-first. If you have a specific sentence that makes it absolutely clear others might appreciate it, as it's a long doc.

Comment: Well, it's not *that* long ;-) The first sentence of my first link and the first two sentences of the second link should suffice... Anyways, it's the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with the d3js code for the [ordinal scale function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/scale/ordinal.js). When running this on Chrome 47.0.2502.0 canary, d3.scale.category20()(c) always returns `#1f77b4`, whatever the value of c is. `#1f77b4` is the first value in the [list of 20 colors](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/scale/category.js)

Updated snippet.

```js
var c20 = d3.scale.category20(),
      col = d3.range(20).map(function(c){
        console.log(c20(c), d3.scale.category20()(c))
        // d3.scale.category20()(c) is always #1f77b4
        return c20(c).replace("#", "0x")
      }),
      log1 = d3.select("#log1"),
      log2 = d3.select("#log2");

    log1.text(c20(1)); // "#aec7e8"
    log2.text(d3.scale.category20()(1)); // "#1f77b4"
    $("#user-agent").text(navigator.userAgent);
```

```css
#log div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="log">
  <div id="log1"></div>
  <div id="log2"></div>
</div>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <p id="user-agent"></p>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
  <div id="log1"></div>
  <div id="log2"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: For some reason the domain is an empty array for this case: `d3.scale.category20()(1)`.  I cut it back to the absolute minimum in my question, you may as well get rid of all that other guff that I left in before.

Comment: I think you put the finger on the problem. Color categories are stored in the range. The domain is [] to start with. A x value gets pushed into the domain every time the function is called, with  `domain.push(x)`. When d3.scale.category20() is used the domain is always []. When a scale instance is stored in a variable, the domain gets updated every time the scale is applied.

Comment: What is odd as well is that the specific c values that you provide don't matter. What matters is how many unique ones you specified so far.  See http://jsfiddle.net/4b6duqdg/7/ for an illustration. Again because of `index.set(x, domain.push(x))` in https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/scale/ordinal.js